# Commit from same user/different source

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Suppose a branch looks like this

```
Project1   
   FolderA   
   FolderB
       File1
```

On same PC with Tortoise client I do two checkouts:

1. one checkout of root folder `Project1` in location `C:\Project1`
2. another checkout of `FolderB` in location `D:\FolderB`

If I work separately in each location and do commits on `File1` from both `C:\Project1` and `D:\FolderB` would SVN have any problem given it's the same user or different locations?

I guess it works because SVN users revisions and it doesn't matter if it's same user or not, correct?

The reason I want to do this is for situations when I am working for few days on something I can't commit yet, but there's something which needs to be fixed related to a previous commit I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guessed,  it works perfectly. The fact that the same user commits from different locations is clearly not a problem and well managed by the tool. It is necessary when a part of repository is common between several projects, developed by the same person in different working copies.
However you should not use the term *checkin* but please use **commit**  which is the right word for svn.

Comment: thanks. one nice thing is that I don't need to do branches.

Comment: If it fully answer your need, thanks to accept the answer.

Comment: @MikeFills - but you **need branching**

Comment: I don't think you need branching in my scenario. Please see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news for you: if `File1` share the same repo-URL in both WC, you *will not be able* to have 2 *independent* lines of changes in 2 WCs.

If changes in `File1` already committed from any Working Copy, second commit with (also modified) `File1` **will be blocked** from second WC: you must update WC, bring changes in `File1` from earlier commit in another WC and **merge changes**, i.e. `File1` in both WCs will contain WC1+WC2 changes.

In order to have possibility to perform independent changes without interference, you **must** to use branching

Comment: Thank you. Here's my scenario: I've been working on a task for few days in a working copy but I'm not finished yet. But now a request comes I should fix something else. So I can just create a new wc, do the fix there and commit. I can now resume working on the initial wc. I can do an update and merge changes and continue working.

Comment: I don't see any problem in the scenario I described